# how to access local drive file from server link

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot trying to save the image on local drive and store the link of image in database but i am facing the problem to access the image through link.

The files is stored on `F:\ImageData\ReportImage\20171218` how can allow the access image in local drive using link like `localhost:8085/ImageData/ReportImage/20171218/sample.jpg`

i have also try setting `server.servlet-path=F:\ImageData` and `server.context-path=F:\ImageData` in `application.property` but problem not solve.

also if i save image in `src/main/resources/static/sample.jpg` can easily access but i want access from some local drive.

please someone help me to solve my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to add resource handlers to spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/images/**")
          .addResourceLocations(new File("F:\ImageData").toURI().toString()); 
    }
}
```

And with this configurations you will be able get images by url `http://<host>/images/<path>` which will try to get image from your disk by path `F:\ImageData\<path>`

More info about this possibility you could find [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources)

Comment: thank for reply but i am working on rest not not mvc ..is there any way to setting  `addResourceHandlers` in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` or in `application.property`

Comment: It's only mapping url `/images/**` to your folder in your machine

Comment: are you sure i need to extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: Found a description from spring documentation:
"By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so you can modify that behavior by adding your own *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* and overriding the addResourceHandlers method."

Comment: you may look at [documantation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html)

Comment: can i get realpath of folder using `/images` ? because i want store the file to the folder and create link

Comment: you mean relative? if so, the <path> after `/images` with all subdirectories will be trying to search in folder `F:\ImageData`